# Can not launch ipad-iphone simulator in libgdx project

Tags: libgdx, ios-simulator, robovm

I am developing a libgdx project. I want to deploy the project to android and ios. The project is working on desktop(MacOS) ,android simulator and android device. However, when I try to launch IOS simulators with gradle or main class, errors are throwed. Also I downloaded some another robovm example. These projects can launch simulators with similar code.

Libgdx IOS main class is as follows:

```
public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate {
@Override
protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
    IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
    return new IOSApplication(new DemoProject(), config);
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
    UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
    pool.close();
}
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.robovm.rt.VM.getStackClasses(II)[Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.robovm.rt.VM.getStackClasses(Native Method)
at org.robovm.rt.bro.Bro.bind(Bro.java:50)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCRuntime.<clinit>(ObjCRuntime.java:43)
at org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.<clinit>(ObjCObject.java:57)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

In fact, I prefer to run gradle.

[image]

But it throws error is as follows:

```
Executing external task 'launchIPhoneSimulator'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:ios:compileJava UP-TO-DATE    
:ios:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ios:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ios:jar UP-TO-DATE
:ios:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:ios:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:ios:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ios:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:ios:test UP-TO-DATE
:ios:check UP-TO-DATE
:ios:build UP-TO-DATE
:ios:launchIPhoneSimulator FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios:launchIPhoneSimulator'.
> Failed to launch IOS Simulator

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.743 secs
/Users/burakdagli/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/1.2.0/unpacked/robovm-1.2.0/bin does not exist.
14:34:13: External task execution finished 'launchIPhoneSimulator'.
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: maybe this help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robovm/_W827FEG2P0

Comment: Would like to bump this really. I struggle with the same error.

Comment: @Burak Start simulator from terminal window and then try to run your app. You can start it from terminal via `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iOS\ Simulator`